# Collecting static of Swagger UI in django project on server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I setup a Swagger configuration on my Django project for a specific endpoint

It worked fully completed on my local machine but when I sent it on server it seems that the static files of drf_yasg cannot be collected and show there were a blank page without any 404 Not Found error, but also on the console it wrote the Js and CSS files are 404 not found

swagger.py

```
from drf_yasg import openapi 
 from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view 
 from django.urls import path 
  
 from requests_app.views import RequestsVS 
 from rest_framework import permissions 
  
  
 single_endpoint_schema_view = get_schema_view( 
     openapi.Info( 
         title="/api/", 
         default_version='v1', 
         description="برای احراز هویت نیاز است تا کلید دریافتی در هدر درخواست ها با عنوان زیر ارسال شود", 
     ), 
     public=True, 
     permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny], 
     patterns=[path('requests/add/outside/', RequestsVS.as_view({'post': 'create_from_outside'}))], 
 ) 
  
 swagger_urlpatterns = [ 
  
     path('swagger/', single_endpoint_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), 
          name='schema-swagger-ui'), 
     path('redoc/', single_endpoint_schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), 
          name='schema-redoc'), 
 ] 
  
  
 urlpatterns = swagger_urlpatterns + [ 
  
 ]
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
  
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 
 ] 
  
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
 # Default primary key field type 
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field 
  
 DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField' 
  
 AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User' 
  
 # Swagger settings 
 SWAGGER_SETTINGS = { 
     'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,  # Set this to True if you're using session authentication 
     'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': { 
         'Bearer': { 
             'type': 'apiKey', 
             'name': 'Authorization', 
             'in': 'header', 
         }, 
     }, 
 }
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 

                   path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 

                   

  

               ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 

  

 urlpatterns += swagger_urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be fixed with one of the following:

1 - Make sure that `drf_yasg` is installed on your server, if not you can use this command to install it

> pip install drf-yasg

---

2 - Verify that the static files are being served correctly on the server. Ensure that the web server configuration is correctly set up to serve static files. If you're using Django's development server (manage.py runserver), it automatically serves static files when the `DEBUG` setting is set to `True`. However, in a production environment, you may need to configure your web server (e.g., `Nginx` I do use it personally) to serve static files.

You can do so by adding this block to your `Nginx` configuration file:

```
    location /static/ { 
        autoindex on; 
        autoindex_exact_size off; 
        alias /your_path/static/;
    }
```

---

3 - Clear the static files cache on the server. Sometimes, cached files may cause issues. You can try running the following command on the server to clear the cache:

> python manage.py collectstatic --clear

Answer (score 0):

Actually on DEV/STAGING server it will work on static of env:

try to run:
python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 static

and then

cp -r /env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/drf_yasg/static/drf-yasg/ /static/

or using django_static_whitenoise
https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_static_whitenoise.php